# Append string to output in shell

Tags: bash, sed, append

I want to append "/*" to the output paths from the below cmd:

**find /home/mba/Desktop/ -type d -name "logs"**

I tried to use sed regex as below:

find /home/mba/Desktop/ -type d -name "logs" | sed -e 's/(^.*)/\1/*/'

But I got the below error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working solution using `awk`:

```
find /home/mba/Desktop/ -type d -name "logs" | awk '{ print $1"/*" }'
```

Or with `sed`:

```
find /home/mba/Desktop/ -type d -name "logs" | sed 's/$/\/\*/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /home/mba/Desktop/ -type d -name "logs" -printf '%p/*\n'
```