# Why won't rm remove files passed in from find or sed?

Tags: bash, stdin, pipeline, rm

I want to pipeline the below commands but the last cmd "rm -rf"is not working i.e. Nothing deleted :

```
find /home/mba/Desktop/ -type d -name "logs" | sed 's/$/\/\*/' | rm -rf
```

No error is returned.

Comment: @CodeGnome: for further information see his posting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24841899/3776858

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rm` command doesn't take filenames from standard input. If you want to pipe from `sed` to `rm`, you can use `xargs`. For example:

```
find /home/mba/Desktop/ -type d -name "logs" | sed 's/$/\/\*/' | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: The sed command is unnecessary. The find command will print out a list of directory paths with the last component of each path being "logs". The rm command with the -r option will then delete the directory recursively

Answer (score 4):

Easier form:

```
find /home/mba/Desktop/ -regex '.*/logs/[^/]+$' -exec rm -fr -- {} +
```

It would match all files residing in any directory having the name `logs`.

If `xargs` is still preferred:

```
find /home/mba/Desktop/ -regex '.*/logs/[^/]+$' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -fr --
```

You can limit the number of files to delete in one go with `-n`:

```
find /home/mba/Desktop/ -regex '.*/logs/[^/]+$' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 2000 rm -fr --
```

- We use `-print0` and `-0` to have `\x00` as delimiter. This would keep the command safe with filenames containing spaces.
- We also add `--` to `rm` so we can remove files whose names start with `-`.

Comment: @chepner You probably mean `-wholename`. But that would also match files greater than 1 level and would cause error on later that file was not found all because the parent was deleted ahead of it. Or maybe `rm -fr` would ignore it anyway but it's still inefficient.

Comment: There's no benefit in restricting the number of arguments to rm; xargs will produce command executions that have as many arguments as can be supported by the os (up to 131072 bytes though this may vary). Restricting the number like this will just force more invocations of the command and slow the whole thing down. The reason you want to use xargs rather than the -exec argument to find is that you want to reduce the number of times you have to execute the command

Comment: @Nick Is that the default behaviour even from the older versions of `xargs`? And is there a document that refers it?

Comment: Hi. The man page for xargs is good (a bit long if you're in a hurry). Xargs behaviour as I described it hasn't changed in many years. The max command line value will have changed over time

Answer (score 1):

"The standard input shall be used to read an input line in response to each prompt specified in the STDOUT section. Otherwise, the standard input shall not be used."

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/rm.html

Examples:

```
yes n | rm -ir dir1 dir2 dir3      # won't delete dir1 dir2 dir3

yes y | rm -ir dir1 dir2 dir3      # delete dir1 dir2 dir3
```